How does resume functionality work in SCORM 1.2?
I am from developer background and my query is regarding a SCORM having no prior experience on it. We are using SCORM 1.2
Problem Statement : When the user will leave the SCORM then it need to resume where it left.
As per the analysis did so far it's been understood that we cannot perform resume operation in SCORM 1.2 but the same can achieve in SCORM 2004.
But in SCORM 2004 we are not getting an response from the event say LMSInitialize
Can you please help here?
Did a lot of RND to understand how SCORM works along with the limitations and hence found in one article that SCORM 1.2 doesn't support resume. But I am not sure what extend can this been considered.

SCORM 1.2 does have resume/bookmarking functionality built into its specification, you'll just need to make sure you are using all the right elements.  There are generally 2 things I look for when I am troubleshooting bookmarking issues.

Does the course issue a location (bookmark) by using its setValue routine to set a value for cmi.core.lesson_location? This is going to be step 1.

Is it "suspending" the attempt so that the LMS does not start the attempt over ignoring any previous locations/bookmarks?  In order to do this, the course will need to set the cmi.core.exit element to "suspend".  This indicates to the LMS that the learner intends to return to the course to resume where they left off.


Note, while SCORM 2004 handles things relatively similarly, the elements are going to be different.  For example, the bookmark element is cmi.location while the exit element is cmi.exit.  I think you ran into an issue with SCORM 2004 initialization for this very reason.  While the SCORM 1.2 initialize function is LMSInitialize, the SCORM 2004 function is Initialize.
I hope this helps.
